# Network Error only occurs when user is on AT&T 5Ge network AND user is logged in

Tags: laravel, react-native, http-headers, authorization, cellular-network

I have built a mobile app using React Native. 
This app connects with a REST API I built using the Laravel framework. 
This API is hosted on a VPS and served over HTTPS.

The mobile app works as intended where I expect it to, with the exception of the following use case:

A user has an iPhone 8+. This user’s carrier is AT&T. The 5Ge, to be specific. 
This user can download the app and install it no problem. 
When they open the app, the app connects to the API, and gets the data to display on the home screen. 
The user can login, using their credentials, which are sent to the API, and the API returns an access token on a valid login.

Every subsequent request, is sent with an Authorization header: Bearer [token]
These requests specifically, never reach the server. All authenticated routes for the API are unreachable for this user.

Users on other networks, like Verizon and TMobile, do not have this issue.

The mobile app uses Axios library for sending HTTP requests. 
A timeout of 25000 (maximum that can be sent on the iOS?) is passed as an option to the authenticated action. The action fails for this user.

The error is caught and then sent to a public route on the API, without an Authorization header in the request. 
This request reaches the server and adds the error message from the request from the mobile app, to the error log on my server.

When I inspect the error that was thrown by the authenticated action failure, it reads “Network error” with a code of 0.

If the timeout is set lower, at 15000, the error thrown by the failed authenticated action is a timeout error, exceeded 15000.

I have contacted AT&T today, and they said we should contact Apple.

After they patched us through to Apple, Apple said issue sounds like it is a cell tower issue, and offered to run diagnostics on the phone.

My question is: Why are the requests that contain an Authorization header Bearer token not able to reach my server when the user is on the AT&T network. Is the bearer token making the request bulky and slowing down the request to where our towers aren’t able to send it?
Or does AT&T have some kind of middleware that would trash the request for some reason? 
Could the Authorization header cause AT&T to handle the request differently and send it some other way and in this way could DNS errors cause the request to fail in this way.

Please help, I hope I have explained it well enough.

Edit: Laravel Passport generates access_token for the authenticated API that is 1000+ characters in length. It looks like I can reduce that by about half. I am going to try that next.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding this is resolved now.

I did two things. I reset my Laravel Passport keys with a specified --length of 1024. 
This resulted in my access tokens being around 557 characters long instead of 1000+

I also made some DNS changes in my subdomain. A scan I did showed a nameserver parent mismatch error between the subdomain and parent domain. I made the changes and got those warnings to go away.

These are the things I did. My two app users who are with the AT&T network carrier tested the app tonight after I did these changes.
They logged in. Opened the timeclock. Clocked in. And that request made it to my server like it was supposed to, with the new shorter access token.

I don't know which one of those two things fixed this issue. But I would probably guess it was the DNS problems that I resolved. I still find it odd that the issue only occured on the AT&T network when with an Authorization token in the header of the request.